# foreign key for tiny integer in laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I have a table named 'platforms' like this

```php
      Schema::create('platforms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->tinyIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name', 100)->unique();

            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and other table visits like

```php
        Schema::create('visits', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('platform_id')->nullable()->constrained('platforms')->restrictOnDelete()->restrictOnUpdate();
            // ...
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I can not make a foreign key from the visits table to the platforms table since the function foregnId function in Laravel set type to bigInteger

```
    public function foreignId($column)
    {
        return $this->addColumnDefinition(new ForeignIdColumnDefinition($this, [
            'type' => 'bigInteger',
            'name' => $column,
            'autoIncrement' => false,
            'unsigned' => true,
        ]));
    }
```

and gets

General error: 1005 Can't create table `panel`.`visits` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table `visits` add constraint `visits_platform_id_foreign` foreign key (`platform_id`) references `platforms` (`id`) on delete restrict on update restrict) error

what should I do to make it happened?

Answer (score 2):

Declare the column yourself manually and then add the FK constraint because [`foreignId`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) forces it to be an unsignedBigInteger as mentioned in the docs.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

Schema::create('visits', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedTinyInteger('platform_id')->nullable();
     $table->foreign('platform_id')->references('id')->on('platforms')->restrictOnDelete()->restrictOnUpdate();
    // ...
    $table->timestamps();
});
```